# Ansible: playbook to deploy VM (Linux)

Tags: templates, unix, ansible, vcenter

I created this playbook to deploy new VM from template.
Now if I try to deploy a new Linux VM it works correctly but the hostname won't be customized
It keeps the same hostname from the template and I don't know why ??

Here is my playbook (this is just a test):

```
- name: Clone multiple VMs
  hosts: localhost 
  gather_facts: false
  vars_files: 
    multiple_vms.yml
  tasks: 
  - name: Clone multiple Ubuntu VMS from Template
    local_action:
      module: vmware_guest
      hostname: "{{ vcenter_hostname }}"
      username: "{{ vcenter_username }}"
      password: "{{ vcenter_password }}"
      validate_certs: no      
      folder: "{{ folder }}"
      template: "{{ vmtemplate }}"
      name: "{{ item }}"
      cluster: "{{ vcenter_cluster }}"
      datacenter: "{{ vcenter_datacenter }}"
      state: poweredon
      networks:
      - name: "{{ network }}"
        type: "{{ network_dhcp_or_static }}"
      hardware:
        memory_mb: {{ number_memory }}
        num_cpus: {{ number_cpu }}
      customization:
        hostname: "{{ servers }}"
        domain : "mydomaine.test"
      #customization_spec: "{{ customization_spec }}"
    with_items: "{{ servers }}"
```

where vars multiple_vms.yml:

```
servers:
  - ubuntu_test01
  - ubuntu_test02
....
```

So I need my new VMS to take the hostname from the servers list (ubuntu_test01.mydomaine.test ..etc)

Thanks for the help

Using vmware_guest and customization option

Answer (score 0):

First, try `hostname: "{{ item }}"`

Second, don't do the loop thing at all.  Make a proper inventory, then:

```
- name: Clone multiple VMs
  hosts: all
  gather_facts: false
  vars_files: 
    multiple_vms.yml
  tasks: 
  - name: Clone multiple Ubuntu VMS from Template
    vmware_guest:
      hostname: "{{ vcenter_hostname }}"
      username: "{{ vcenter_username }}"
      password: "{{ vcenter_password }}"
      validate_certs: no      
      folder: "{{ folder }}"
      template: "{{ vmtemplate }}"
      name: "{{ ansible_hostname }}"
      cluster: "{{ vcenter_cluster }}"
      datacenter: "{{ vcenter_datacenter }}"
      state: poweredon
      networks:
      - name: "{{ network }}"
        type: "{{ network_dhcp_or_static }}"
      hardware:
        memory_mb: {{ number_memory }}
        num_cpus: {{ number_cpu }}
      customization:
        hostname: "{{ ansible_hostname }}"
        domain : "mydomaine.test"
    delegate_to: localhost
```

N.B.: `local_action` is deprecated.  Use `delegate_to: localhost`.

Comment: I tried with hostname: "{{ item }}" but it doesn't work.

So I tried your suggestion : creating a real inventory where new vm are listed, I just changed ansible_hostname by inventory_hostname and new VMS are correctly created into my vCenter but server hostname (not the VM name !) didn't change :/ ...

VM names are ok: It took the name from the inventory list
Server Hostname are not customized as I wish with {{ inventory_hostname }}

Comment: You can execute another task to set the hostname.